why is bash variable expansion not working
In my script I have:
echo "In set class path $JAVA_HOME"

  if [ ! -x "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java ]; then
    echo "problem $JAVA_HOME /bin/java is not executable"
    echo "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java "
    echo "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
    echo "This environment variable is needed to run this program"
    echo "NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE"
    exit 1
  fi

Output:
In set class path /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64
 /bin/java is not executable-openjdk-amd64
/bin/java vm/java-21-openjdk-amd64
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Output with comments:
In set class path /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64  ## works as expected
/bin/java is not executable-openjdk-amd64   ## loses 'problem', doesn't expand $JAVA_HOME Variable reference,  appends the end of the $JAVA_HOME string ('-openjdk-amd64') at the end of the echoed output.
/bin/java vm/java-21-openjdk-amd64  ## doesn't expand $JAVA_HOME Variable reference,  appends part of the $JAVA_HOME string ('vm/java-21-openjdk-amd64')
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64  ## works as expected
...
What is going on?  why are the variable expansions failing or putting text in weird places?
Since the $JAVA_HOME variable is defined, and the java executable is at the specified path, no output should be generated. Instead the Tomcat startup fails.

Try adding \n at the end of the echo lines inside the quotes.. so : echo “text \n” - and see what the results are.

Could it be that JAVA_HOME contains some invisible character? What does xxd <<$JAVA_HOME say?

JAVA_HOME almost certainly ends with a (normally-invisible) carriage return character, probably because some file (the script or a file it reads from) has DOS/Windows line endings. This causes printed after the carriage return to show up before it in the terminal. See my answer here for an example of how this works.

Yup, the problem was some /r/n line separators in the setenv.sh script.  eliminating the /r characters solved the problem.
